# Suppose $AB=I$, where A has full rank. Is $BA=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that the title statement is correct for square matrices $A,B$.

What about non-square matrices with full rank?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $A$ is full rank and it is, say, $m\times n$, then $m< n$, (because it isn't a square matrix it can't be the case that $m=n$). Furthermore if $B$ is $n\times p$, for some natural number $p$, for $BA$ to be defined, necessarily $p=m$.

Summarizing:

1. $A$ is $m\times n$
2. $B$ is $n\times m$
3. $AB=I_m$
4. Thesis is $BA=I_n$

Assume $BA=I_n$.

A known property is that the $\text{rank}(XY)\leq \min \left(\left\{\text{rank}(X), \text{rank}(Y)\right\}\right)$.

So $n=\text{rank}(I_n)=\text{rank}(BA)\leq \min(\left\{m,n\right\})=m<n$.

This shows that not only does it fail, it always fails just as long as the product $BA$ is defined.

Comment: This works when you use the definition of full rank being that there are no null rows when the matrix is reduced to its row echelon form. If you use the symmetric definition that a matrix is full rank when its rank = min(m,n) this argument still works, but you have to fix m < n by assumption and then derive the same contradiction. This doesn't lose generality because you can do the same thing if you fix n < m.

Answer (score 7):

$$(1\;0)\binom 10=1\;,\;\;\;\text{yet}\;\;\;\binom10(1\;0)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\neq I$$

Comment: Correct.  It is defined.  And gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true, even when multiplication is defined.  Look at $A=(1\quad 1)$ and $B=(2 \quad -1)^T$ (where $T$ indicates transpose).

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. You can however use it to create a right null space for $A$ (it will have square dimension):
$$A\left( BA - I\right) = 0$$
Because
$$A\left( BA - I\right) = ABA - A = IA - A = 0$$