# Can an $n\times n$ matrix be reduced to a smaller matrix in any sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A friend of mine asked me if it was possible to convert a square matrix into an equal matrix of a smaller dimension (but still square). I told him in many ways this wouldn't make sense, as matrix multiplication wouldn't be conserved, and the whole concept of linear operators probably wouldn't be able to retain its normal definition. However, I thought that maybe in some weird (different) sense this could be possible. If such a manipulation was possible, I'm sure many matrix problems could be made much simpler.

**Does any sense or mathematical world exist where this is established? Does this ring any bells for anybody?**

Comment: The eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & 0\\ c & d & 0\\ 0 & 0 &\lambda\end{bmatrix}$ are the eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ and $\lambda$. Is this satisfactory?

Comment: If $A$ is not square, then $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ share the same non-null eigenvalues and one is smaller than the other. Is this anywhere close to what you want?

Comment: @GitGud For your first comment, that's definitely something worth noting (I think), and every invertible matrix can be reduced to a diagonal matrix. For your second comment, can any $n\times n$ square matrix be broken down into two smaller $n\times m$ and $m\times n$ matrices?

Comment: With smaller I suppose you mean $m<n$. The answer is no because, for instance, $n=\text{rank}(I_n)=\text{rank}(M_{n\times m}N_{m\times n})\leq \min(m,n)=m$.

Comment: With regards to the question in your latest comment, see also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579450/if-ab-i-a-is-full-rank-but-not-square-matrix-shall-we-have-ba-i).