# Confusion in understanding some part of a proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading an answer, but I am not able to understand the first line.

Full rank means rank $A$ is $n$ then how are we concluding that $m<n$. Should not it be other way round.

Maybe I am missing something.

Thanks.

> If $A$ is full rank and it is, say, $m\times n$, then $m< n$, (because
>   it isn't a square matrix it can't be the case that $m=n$). Furthermore
>   if $B$ is $n\times p$, for some natural number $p$, for $BA$ to be
>   defined, necessarily $p=m$.
>
> Summarizing:
>
> 1. $A$ is $m\times n$
> 2. $B$ is $n\times m$
> 3. $AB=I_m$
> 4. Thesis is $BA=I_n$
>
> Assume $BA=I_n$.
>
> A known property is that the $\text{rank}(XY)\leq \min
> > \left(\left\{\text{rank}(X), \text{rank}(Y)\right\}\right)$.
>
> So $n=\text{rank}(I_n)=\text{rank}(BA)\leq
> > \min(\left\{m,n\right\})=m<n$.
>
> This shows that not only does it fail, it always fails just as long as
>   the product $BA$ is defined.

[If $AB=I$, A is full rank, but not square matrix, shall we have $BA=I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579450/if-ab-i-a-is-full-rank-but-not-square-matrix-shall-we-have-ba-i)

Comment: The answer to your question is in the comment on the answer you link to, by Doug McClean. (And what you write — “full rank means the rank of $A$ is $n$” — isn’t right, either. Here is the fact using the usual definition of full rank: a matrix (possibly non-square) has full rank when its rank is as large as possible. That means the rank of a matrix with full rank is the minimum of the number of rows and the number of columns.)

Comment: @symplectomorphic So here author is assuming that rank (A) is m?

Comment: As Doug explained, GitGud was using a different (somewhat nonstandard, in my view) definition of “full rank.” The way to do the proof using the definition I just gave is to break the proof into two cases: first assume $m<n$ and use full rank to conclude the rank is $m$; then assume $n<m$ and use full rank to conclude the rank is $n$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. @symplectomorphic It is clear to me now. :)

Comment: If $A$ is $m \times n$ and rank is full, we conclude $m = \text{dim}(\text{Im}(A))= \text{rank}(A) \leq \min(m,n) \leq m \Rightarrow m\leq n$.